# Which (if any) of these three alternative sentence constructions is most understandable for use in function documentation comments?

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-choice, syntax, writing

I'm writing documentation (i.e. code comments) for a JavaScript function with multiple parameters.
In specifying the purposes of each of the parameters, I have encountered some difficulty in making the description for some of them both *concise* and clear. As it currently stands, I have this sentence:

> **1.** The span parameters determine how far from the respective margins the region where it is possible for ore deposits to be centered extends.

This seems somewhat difficult to take in, and would probably cause the average reader to have to *reread* the sentence to understand what's going on. I believe the problem is the separation of the verb "extends" from its subject "region" by the intervening clause which begins with the word "where."

I don't want to split this into more than one sentence, as the descriptions of all the other function parameters are single sentences.

So, to avoid the confusion caused by stranding the word "extends" in the original, I thought of rephrasing the sentence like this:

> **2.** The span parameters determine how far from the respective margins **extends** the region where it is possible for ore deposits to be centered.

But, I actually like this version *less*, since it has a very unusual word order (verb *before* subject). This could lead the reader to think "extends" is being used *transitively*, which it is not.

Using the normal word order would however give the following:

> **3.** The span parameters determine how far from the respective margins the region **extends** where it is possible for ore deposits to be centered.

This has its own problem, though: now it looks like the clause beginning with "where" modifies the verb "extends" instead of the noun "region." This is not the meaning I intend (although it is similar enough that it shouldn't cause any significant misunderstandings).

Although I'm confident that all three possibilities are grammatically correct, none of them seems particularly *clear*. As of now, I'm sticking with the first one (sentence **1**), but wanted to get a second opinion to see which phrasing a person who *isn't* already familiar with the (intended) meaning would prefer. (I recognize that a lot of contributors here are probably better writers than me, as well!)

Furthermore, if there is some alternative I've missed that would avoid all the problems of **1**, **2** and **3**, I'm not at all attached to those particular variants and would be glad to make more significant changes following your suggestions. Any input is greatly appreciated!

---

*While this is kind of outside of the scope of the question, I will include the function signature as well, in case it helps clarify the sentence's intended meaning:*
`var oreDeposit = function(centerXZMargin, centerXZSpan, centerYMargin, centerYSpan, minBlocks, maxBlocks) {`
(I'm attempting to describe the use of the `centerXZSpan` and `centerYSpan` parameters.)

**And, here is a visual showing a cross-section of an example region, along with two deposit positions that are possible and one that is not.**  [image]

Comment: Would the following sentence be technically correct? "The span parameters determine how far from their respective margins the ore deposits can be centered." Or alternately, "The span parameters determine how far the ore deposits can be centered from their respective margins."

Comment: You need to hire an editor. I see no reason for this question to be considered OK here. That said: **Span parameters determine how far from the respective margins the region extends and the center of the ore deposits**.

Comment: @YonKuma Yes, that first one is an excellent alternative! If you add that as an answer, I'll accept it. The second one doesn't work for me, because "respective margins" is meant to refer to the XZ and Y directions (belonging to both the margin parameters already described and to the span parameters), not to the ore deposits themselves.

Comment: @Lambie I think hiring an editor would be disproportionate for this. The context is a script I'm using to generate terrain for an adventure map I will be uploading to PlanetMinecraft soon. While I intend the **map** to be part of my portfolio when applying to join the Minecraft Partner Program, *the script itself is unlikely to be read/interacted with by a large number of people*. I'm only documenting it because it's good practice, for my own future reference, and in case anyone else on the forum may want to use or modify the algorithm for their own projects.

Comment: @Lambie Thanks for your suggestion, but I'm not clear on the meaning of "and the center of the ore deposits." There will be multiple deposits, each with a center within "the region" which extends from margin to margin. The deposits are placed randomly (by their centers) at various coordinates throughout the eligible region. So, the centers can never be outside the region, but the deposit's edges may extend slightly past the margins. (This is by design.)

Comment: @QuackE.Duck If that's the meaning, then all of your examples are incorrect, as is my suggestion. Depending on the actual implementation, the correct description would be either "the maximum diameter of an ore deposit," or "the maximum distance an ore deposit can exceed the margins."

Comment: @YonKuma I believe my previous comment may have been unclear. I'm not referring to the maximum diameter of a deposit: each deposit is a *small* cube within "the region" which is a *much larger* cube. To get really specific, the maximum diameter of a deposit is 3 blocks and the "region" is 14 blocks extending from the *margins*, which are 1 block away from the entire structure (16*Y*16)'s edges. So, 1 + 14 = 15, leaving another 1 block on the far side of the region. Deposit centers must be within the inner 14*Y*14, but their edges (at most 1 block away from the center in either direction)

Comment: can extend into the outermost block of the 16*Y*16 region.

Comment: If this question is actually on topic (which @Lambie has me doubting...), maybe it could benefit from a diagram?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150469/discussion-between-yonkuma-and-quack-e-duck).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Combining @TimR's answer *("The span parameters establish boundaries...")* and @YonKuma's comment *("...the ore deposits can be centered")*, and also incorporating @swmcdonnell's feedback that the word "extends" was a cause of confusion in my original version, I have revised the sentence as follows:

> **The span parameters determine the dimensions, measured starting from the respective margins, of the region where it is possible for ore deposits to be centered.**

Answer (score 1):

It's really important to include the units, because that's what the numbers represent. Are they pixels? inches? blocks?

How about this:

> The span parameters specify the number of blocks that the respective margins are extended to create the region where ore deposits can be centered.

Comment: I think this may be about a function that locates probable physical locations for ore deposits, so the unit is likely to be whichever of "miles" or "kilometers" is standard for large distances in the region. Further, I don't think it's the margins that are extended, it's the region within which the ore deposits can be centered that is "extended" by the parameter.

Comment: That's why the units are critical. The parameter is a number - what does that number represent? I find it difficult to believe that it's miles when it's extending from a margin. We just have different interpretations of what's been described.

Comment: The units are in fact blocks, and I will revise the code comments to make that clear. Thanks for the pointer there! @YonKuma you are correct about the meaning of "extended."

Comment: So if you're extending the region, not the margins, why do you even mention the margins?

Comment: @swmcdonnell The margins are also function parameters, and are described in the previous comment before the one I'm asking about here. They determine the bounds of the region in three directions (bottom, -x, and -z within a cube-shaped area).

Comment: Right, so the parameters extend the margins outward by a certain number of  blocks, and that defines the region where the ore deposits can be centered, correct? Isn't that what I said?

Comment: @swmcdonnell The parameters define a region where the ore deposits can be centered, just like you said. But, they don't "extend the margin," they specify the extent of the region (in green on the diagram) which *extends outward **from** the margin*. In the picture, the value of the margin is 1 for the x and z coordinates, and 2 for the y coordinate (counted upward from the bottom of the cube). The "span" parameters in the diagram have values of 14 in the x and z directions and 5 in the y direction. You have convinced me to choose a different word than "extends," as it seems to cause confusion.

Comment: OK, yes that was a poor word choice. Got it, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> The span parameters determine how far from the respective margins the region where it is possible for ore deposits to be centered extends.

*The span parameters  establish  boundaries for determining whether an ore deposit is valid: deposits are valid only if they do not extend, in whole or in part, beyond any boundary.*

**How is the  *contiguity* of an ore deposit determined?**

Comment: Hi, @TimR, thanks for answering! The deposits are *not* guaranteed to be contiguous. It is possible for a deposit to consist only of separate, non-adjacent blocks -- as long as all blocks comprising the deposit are within a 3*3*3 cube centered at the chosen coordinates.

Comment: TimR, @swmcdonnell How about, "The span parameters determine the dimensions, measured starting from the respective margins, of the region where it is possible for ore deposits to be centered"?

Comment: Also note that it *is not possible* for an "invalid" deposit to be generated in the first place, since the span parameters are used to determine the bounds of the random integers which are generated for the ore deposits' center coordinates.

Comment: Ah, your "invalid deposit in red" on the diagram threw me off.

Comment: Oh, maybe I should remove that part? It was supposed to be hypothetical but I see how it could be confusing.

Comment: Edited to fix the picture and its description